# Exchanging sprite content in cocos2d-x 3

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I exchange sprite content with this code:

```
mySprite->setTexture(Director::getInstance()->getTextureCache()->addImage("newImage.png"));
```

The problem is that `newImage.png` is much smaller than the old content image of the sprite. But cocos2d-x scales `newImage.png` to have the same size as `oldImage.png`. How I can prevent this scaling. I need `newImage.png` to be its natural size, but to appear in the coordinates of `oldImage.png` (I want to retain the same sprite object, as far as I have a pointer on it and also the same position and same anchor point. That's why I use `setTexture` just to change the image.)

Comment: Did you tried method `initWithTexture`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mySprite->setTexture("newImage.png");
```

This sets the content Rect too.

Comment: The Texture's rect is not changed. This states in the comments for this method =)

Answer (score 0):

Well, this may not be the cleanest way, but it seems the most straigthforward to me :

```
Sprite *newSprite = Sprite::create("newImage.png");
newSprite->setAnchorPoint(mySprite->getAnchorPoint());
newSprite->setPosition(mySprite->getPosition());

mySprite->removeFormParentAndCleanup(true);
mySprite = newSprite;  // <-- magic happens here
```

So basically you create a new sprite, place it based in old sprites position/anchor and then after removing the old one, you assigne the `mySprite` variable to point to the same place as `newSprite`.